# Scroll chart with mouse wheel in TeeChart

Tags: swt, teechart

Default way to scroll chart is to drag mouse holding right button. I need to scroll with mouse wheel. I haven't found any API to enable/disable mouse wheel scrolling.

I also tried to add MouseWheelListener to the chart itself, but it never gets called.

Is it possible to use mouse wheel in TeeChart lib?

My application is Eclipse RCP using SWT.

Comment: First of all, please add a link to the library you are using. Second, please consider posting a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) so we can reproduce what you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine for me with TeeChart Java SWT in Eclipse:

```
Bar bar1 = new Bar(tChart1.getChart());
bar1.fillSampleValues();

tChart1.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseScrolled(MouseEvent arg0) {
        Axis tmpA = tChart1.getAxes().getLeft();
        double tmpInc = tmpA.getRange()/10;
        if (arg0.count>0)
            tmpA.setMinMax(tmpA.getMinimum()+tmpInc, tmpA.getMaximum()+tmpInc);
        else
            tmpA.setMinMax(tmpA.getMinimum()-tmpInc, tmpA.getMaximum()-tmpInc);
    }
});
```

Comment: Indeed it's the way to go. I had exactly the same code, but it didn't work until I manually set focus on the chart.