# mouse wheel moved not fired in TeeChart

Tags: java, swing, teechart

I have the problem described in the thread below:

[Scroll chart with mouse wheel in TeeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515757/scroll-chart-with-mouse-wheel-in-teechart)

I setup the example Java demo from oficcial site and I run it normally, I can see different types of graph etc.

The problem is I can not add MouseWheelListener to the TChart.  In the thread above, someone answered as following :
"The following code works fine for me with TeeChart Java SWT in Eclipse:"
Also another user commented as :
"Indeed it's the way to go. I had exactly the same code, but it didn't work until I manually set focus on the chart. "

Fist of all The code given in the answer does not work in Eclipse Indigo. Second, It's been a while since the answer is given, lib has been changed to some extent, there is no more "mouseScrolled" event. 
there is a an event named "mouseWheelMoved" .  I could not, for the life of me, get this event to be fired.

Any suggestions, examples, opinions are greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Example Code:

```
JFrame frame = new Jframe();
JPanel contentPane; 
TChart tChart2 = new TChart();
tChart2.setGraphics3D(null);
tChart2.setBounds(new Rectangle(6, 71, 572, 268));
// Mouse Wheel Listener
tChart2.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.out.println("mouseWheelMoved worked");
        }
});
contentPane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.add(tChart2);
```

Comment: Questions seeking help must include **the desired behavior**, **a specific problem or error** and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Desired behivour : firing of  MouseWheelMoved event                                                                                                                 So my problem is clear. I will add example reproducible code shortly.

Comment: @ShouRisha Of what type is `contentPane` ? Looks like you're not using SWT, but rather Swing

Comment: @Baz  Aplogies. I updated the code. Yes I'm using swing. I created JFrame for the example code, I'm using similar setting in my actual code. I get contentPane from Jframe object and add the  Chart  to it.  I will update the tags now. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ShouRisha I can't help you in that case. Works just fine when using SWT.

Comment: Thanks @Baz Maybe my problem direclty related with Swing-SWT connection. I'm still searching on the matter on internet. Best regards.

Comment: @ShouRisha You're using Swing, so why mention SWT at all?

Comment: If you mean the tag, It was my mistake. Original thread which contained similar problem, had SWT tag. I mistakenly copied without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The MouseWheel event was fired in TeeChart Java for SWT but wasn't in TeeChart Java for Swing.

I've added it to the public tracker ([here](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1555)) and already fixed it for the next maintenance release.

For those with the sources, the fix consists on a couple of small changes at TChart.java:

```
--- a/Swing/src/com/steema/teechart/TChart.java
+++ b/Swing/src/com/steema/teechart/TChart.java
@@ -21,6 +21,8 @@ import java.awt.Toolkit;
 import java.awt.datatransfer.*;

 import com.steema.teechart.events.FrameworkMouseEvent;
+import com.steema.teechart.events.FrameworkMouseWheelEvent;
+
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.beans.*;
 import java.io.*;
@@ -1405,7 +1407,16 @@ public class TChart extends JComponent implements Serializable, IChart,
                                       e.getX(),e.getY(),e.getClickCount(),
                                       true,e.getButton());
     }
-
+    
+    private FrameworkMouseWheelEvent getFrameworkEvent(MouseWheelEvent e)
+    {
+      return new FrameworkMouseWheelEvent(e.getComponent(), e.getID(),
+                                           e.getWhen(), e.getModifiers(),
+                                           e.getX(), e.getY(), e.getClickCount(),
+                                           true, e.getScrollType(),
+                                           e.getScrollAmount(), e.getWheelRotation());
+    }
+    
     protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
         chart.cancelMouse = false;

@@ -1439,6 +1450,15 @@ public class TChart extends JComponent implements Serializable, IChart,


     protected void processMouseWheelEvent(MouseWheelEvent e) {
+       chart.cancelMouse = false;
+       if (_allowMouse) {
+           FrameworkMouseWheelEvent fwe = getFrameworkEvent(e);
+           
+           if (!chart.cancelMouse) {
+                super.processMouseWheelEvent(fwe);
+            }
+        }
     }

     private boolean _allowMouse = true;
--
```

And a new class: FrameworkMouseWheelEvent.java:

```
package com.steema.teechart.events;

import java.awt.Component;

public class FrameworkMouseWheelEvent extends java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FrameworkMouseWheelEvent(Component source, int id, long when, int modifiers, int x, int y, int clickCount,
            boolean popupTrigger, int scrollType, int scrollAmount, int wheelRotation) {
        super(source, id, when, modifiers, x, y, clickCount, popupTrigger, scrollType, scrollAmount, wheelRotation);
    }

    public FrameworkMouseWheelEvent(Component source, int id, long when, int modifiers, int x, int y, int xAbs,
            int yAbs, int clickCount, boolean popupTrigger, int scrollType, int scrollAmount, int wheelRotation) {
        super(source, id, when, modifiers, x, y, xAbs, yAbs, clickCount, popupTrigger, scrollType, scrollAmount, wheelRotation);
    }

    public FrameworkMouseWheelEvent(Component source, int id, long when, int modifiers, int x, int y, int xAbs,
            int yAbs, int clickCount, boolean popupTrigger, int scrollType, int scrollAmount, int wheelRotation,
            double preciseWheelRotation) {
        super(source, id, when, modifiers, x, y, xAbs, yAbs, clickCount, popupTrigger, scrollType, scrollAmount, wheelRotation,
                preciseWheelRotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Yeray Thanks posting the solution. I have only demo classes in jars. I will look for libs with the source files. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @ShouRisha contact "sales at steema dot com" and we'll try to provide a patch or a test version.

Comment: Thanks. I will contact steema. Best regards.